# How do I create a variable based on selected characters from row.names?

Tags: r

I have an object in R that looks like this

```
                        Value
    AAAAA.1569.12.32    5
    C.4586.25.65        2
    AAAAA.4568.32.54    2
    BBB.5462.23.32      3
    BBB.5425.36.25      5
    C.5658.25.24        4
```

and I want it to look like this

```
                       Value    Name
     AAAAA.1569.12.32   5       AAAAA
     C.4586.25.65       2       C
     AAAAA.4568.32.54   2       AAAAA
     BBB.5462.23.32     3       BBB
     BBB.5425.36.25     5       BBB
     C.5658.25.24       4       C
```

I've used

```
df$Name = rownames(df)
```

but this puts the the entire string from row.names in the "Name" column.  Somehow, I just want to use the text from before the period (no periods or numbers).  Does anyone know how I might do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically, keep all text prior to the first `.` character:

```
df$Name <- sub('[.].*','', rownames(df))
```

In a regular expression, `.` means to match any character.  So to match a literal dot, the character must be escaped.  However, within a character class (bounded by `[` and `]`), the `.` does represent a literal dot.  That is, `[.]` matches a literal dot only.

Following that is `.*` which matches any number of any characters.

Thus, the expression matches everything from the first literal `.` to the end of the string, and replaces it with the empty string.

Comment: I don't quite understand how the first 2 things in the sub command work... any chance you could explain this?

Comment: Thanks Matthew, your explanation really helped!

Comment: I understand your explanation, but if I want to remove "AAAAA." from the first line, to give "1569.12.32", why doesn't this work: df$Name <- sub('*.[.]','', rownames(df))

Comment: Because that matches the first `.` and everything that follows it, and replaces it with nothing.  Here is one way to get what you wish for your last comment: `sub('^[^.]*.', '', rownames(df))`.

Answer (score 2):

Here are 2 alternative ways.  1 base and 1 in qdap:

```
## df <- structure(list(Value = c(5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L)), .Names = "Value", class = "data.frame", row.names = c("AAAAA.1569.12.32", 
##     "C.4586.25.65", "AAAAA.4568.32.54", "BBB.5462.23.32", "BBB.5425.36.25", 
##     "C.5658.25.24"))

df$Name <- sapply(strsplit(rownames(df), "\\."), "[", 1)

library(qdap)
df$Name <- beg2char(rownames(df), ".")
```

Comment: Is `beg2char` just something like `substring(rownames(df),1,regexpr("\\.",rownames(df))-1)`?

Comment: The code's not hidden at all.  It uses regex `beg2char` in command line.  It can do more complicated stuff such as `beg2char(rownames(df), ".", 2); beg2char(rownames(df), ".", 3)`  Related see `char2end`.  char stands for any character.

Comment: Thanks Tyler, I am just using your qdap solution for a related problem.  =)